# Forcing Invaders To Leave

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

Is there a way to banish an invader?
If he's just running around not necessarily trying to kill me, can I somehow make him leave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest either shutting the game off and restarting in offline mode, or killing yourself with a ring of sacrifice.

In order to prevent abuse, there's no way to force an invader to leave. The intent is for one person to kill the other and not let either leave until that's been achieved (which is why your situation is so frustrating).

Comment: Just be careful when disconnecting - the game is designed to "punish" those who bail on invaders, as this is not how the game was meant to be played. If you are punished, you will lose the ability to summon friendly phantoms, and likely be invaded more often. Using the "Bone of Order" can reverse this.

Comment: Well don't do it every time, but if someone joins your game and is just griefing and blocking your progress, it should be okay every once in a while.

Comment: If there's truly no way then I suppose this will make do. I don't want to use the 'Seed of a Tree Giant' as they are rare to come by.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there isn't a good clean solution for this. Bad invaders are going to come sometimes and there's not much you can do about it. Sorry, man.